# comparing systemenum type against string with powershell

Tags: powershell

I am placing `Get-ExecutionPolicy` into a variable called `$POL`. I am then attempting to check the Policy with something like this:

```
if ($POL-is "Restricted") {write-host("something")}
```

I'm running in the issue, I think, that my POL variable is of type SystemEnum, and I'm checking it against a string.  Even if I cast the POL variable as a string, `[STRING]$POL` ... comparing it against `Restricted` gives me a new error.

cant convert value of type `System.String` to type `System.Type`.

```
if ([string]$POL-is "Restricted") {write-host("something")}
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: Don't use `-is`, but compare with `-eq`

Answer (score 3):

As [Theo mentions in the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57833985/comparing-systemenum-type-against-string-with-powershell#comment102097050_57833985), you're using the wrong comparison operator!

`-is` is a *type* operator, so it checks whether the value of `$POL` is of a type with the typename `Restricted`.

Use the `-eq` operator to compare the string value instead:

```
$POL -eq 'Restricted'
```

or against the actual enum value:

```
$POL -eq [Microsoft.PowerShell.ExecutionPolicy]::Restricted
```